# Система сообщений для связи админа с пользователем?

Tags: форум

Можно ли организовать на странице систему сообщений подобно тому, как это сделано на хабре, или, к примеру у Сергея Чикуёнка chikuyonok.ru/html-css/, без базы данных и можно сказать почти полного отсутствия опыта программирования? 
Знаю, что существуют готовые решения для создания форумов, но они слишком навороченные и в них много того, что для моей задачи попросту будет излишним. Возможно их можно настроить под свои нужды, но делать этого раньше мне не приходилось.

Существует ли возможность реализации сей задачи в описанном контексте, если да, поделитесь полезными ссылками к вопросу, также буду благодарен за иную полезную по теме информацию.

Нечто подобное, как на хабре или любом ином ресурсе, где — посетитель спросил, админ ответил, и просмотреть и прочить обмен сообщений мог любой зашедший на страницу человек.Скрин с хабра ↓

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, подключите один из доступных сервисов, реализующих такой функционал. Выбор довольно большой, есть и бесплатные варианты. Интеграция с собственным сайтом, как правило, не сложная и хорошо документированная. Как вариант:
[Disqus](https://disqus.com/), [HyperComments](https://www.hypercomments.com/), [Cacle](http://cackle.me/), [SVcament](http://svkament.ru/) у многих социальных сетей тоже есть виджеты подключаемые к сайту, с таким функционалом.

Comment: Ссылки глянул, похоже на то, что искал. На первый взгляд, установка не показалась сложной. Получше ознакомлюсь с документацией и после возьмусь за установку. Надеюсь, получится. За ссылки спасибки.